# Insert Spaces into string at an index

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, slice

I'm trying to do this Codewars problem.

> **Task**
>
> > In this simple Kata your task is to create a function that turns a string into a Mexican Wave. You will be passed a string and you must return that string in an array where an uppercase letter is a person standing up.
>
> **Rules**
>
> > 1. The input string will always be lower case but maybe empty.
> > 2. If the character in the string is whitespace then pass over it as if it was an empty seat.
> >        Example
> >        wave("hello") => ["Hello", "hEllo", "heLlo", "helLo", "hellO"]

[My code so far is hosted on this repl.it](https://repl.it/@RylanAlbach/InfantileTenderDeveloper)

My thought process is as follows:

1. Turn argument into array
2. manipulate each index of the array at index and then readjust previous index to make a wave pattern
3. turn array into string
4. reinsert spaces before logging it to console and restarting the loop

I'm pretty stuck and my mind is stuck on how to use

`for(var j = 0; j < indexSpaceNumber.length; j++){
      //join and add in the spaces at their former index before returning string
      strToArray[indexSpaceNumber[j]].slice(0, " ");
      }`

to insert the spaces into the string.

If there's any guidance or tips it would be much appreciated. I feel like I'm close, but so frustratingly far.

Comment: Can you please add case for multiple words in your input?

Answer (score 2):

The main idea would be:

1. Iterate the characters
2. Replace the character in the original string with an uppercase version

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the string to an array, and map each item to a new string. If the character is a space return something falsy (en empty string in the example). After the creating the array, filter all falsy values:

```js
const wave = str =>
  Array.from(str, (c,i) => // convert the string to an array
    // replace the character with an uppercase version in the original string
    c === ' ' ?
    ''
    :
    `${str.substring(0, i)}${c.toUpperCase()}${str.substring(i + 1)}`
  ).filter(c => c)

const result = wave("hello") 

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go over each char in string and build
`Slice str from start till current char + current char to upper case + Slice str from current char to end`

```js
const wave = str => {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    res.push(`${str.slice(0, i)}${str[i].toUpperCase()}${str.slice(i + 1)}}`);
  }
  return res;
};

console.log(wave("hi my name is rylan"));

// Alternate way to do with Array.splice
const wave2 = str => {
  const res = [];
  for (let i in str) {
    const temp = Array.from(str);
    temp.splice(i, 1, temp[i].toUpperCase());
    res.push(temp)
  } 
  return res.map(x => x.join(''));
};

console.log(wave2("hi my name is rylan"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For string with spaces

```js
function wave(str) {
  let res = []
  str.toLowerCase().split('').forEach((v, i) => {
    if(v == ' ') return;
    res.push( str.substr(0, i) + v.toUpperCase() + str.substr(i + 1) )
  });
  return res
}

console.log(wave("hello hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go recursive ;)

You know that for a string of length *n* you need an array of the same length. That's your exit condition.

You can use the length of the array at each iteration to work out the shape of the next string:

```
hello []            [Hello]              0: uppercase 1st char and append
hello [Hello]       [Hello hEllo]        1: uppercase 2nd char and append
hello [Hello hEllo] [Hello hEllo heLlo]  2: uppercase 3rd char and append
...
```

```js
const wave =
  (str, arr = []) =>
    str.length === arr.length
      ? arr
      : wave
          ( str
          , [ ...arr
            ,   str.slice(0, arr.length)
              + str[arr.length].toUpperCase()
              + str.slice(arr.length + 1)
            ]
          );

console.log(wave('hello'));
```